# What role does hashCode play when comparing two objects?

Tags: java, object, collision

I've decided to study some primary documentation in Java. I've started with `Object` class and I am looking at the `equals` method. I know that `equals` is using `hashCode` method. Although, `hashCode` returns int so there are a limited number of unique hashcodes that can be generated.

What will happen when I try to compare two **diffrent** objects that have the same `hashCode`? Is this even posible?

Comment: `equals` does not use `hashCode`. Although, they do have a contract between each other that must be honored.

Comment: equal objects must have same hashcode, but not vice versa.

Comment: When you define a equals or compareTo (when you redefined these methods from Object class) you must be sure that the two objects that you compare are from the same class, with instanceof() for example.

a.equals(b) => a.hashCode() == b.hashCode(); But a.hashCode() == b.hashCode !=> a.equals(b);

Comment: I have edited your question as an example of how you could spend some time in making it presentable.

Comment: @CKing: *equals does not use hashCode* ... this is not strictly true.  The contract for `equals` does not require the use of  the hashcode, but equals comparisons may use it as an optimization if the implementation chooses to.

Comment: @scottb Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "but equals comparisons may use it as an optimization if the implementation chooses to"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Two objects can have the same hashcode. However, `hashcode` plays no role when comparing two objects.  If you want to check if two objects of a class are `equal`, override `equals` and define when two objects of the class should be considered equal. If you want to compare if one object of a class is less than/greater than the other (usually while sorting collection), implement `Comparable` and override the `compareTo` method. (You can also implement `Comparator`)

If you ever want to store an object in a `HashSet` or use it as a key in a `HashMap`, make sure that you override the `hashCode` method or your objects/keys will most likely be stored in different buckets resulting in duplicates.

Don't forget to override `equals` in classes that you create. If you don't do this, two references to an object of your class will only be equal if they refer to the same object.

You can read more about the equals and hashCode methods in the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) documentation.

Comment: I believe your statement that `Object.equals()` would cause all objects in a `HashSet` or all keys in a `HashMap` to be stored in the same bucket is incorrect.  The javadocs page you link to states that `Object.equals()` does return unique integers for unique objects.

Comment: @SteveBrandli Can you point me to the part of my answer that claims that **Object.equals** would cause keys to be stored in the same bucket? I can't seem to find that in the above answer. Did you mean `hashCode` in which case you are right. Corrected the answer

Comment: Again, *"...hashcode plays no role when comparing two objects"* is not strictly correct.

Comment: @scottb Can you elaborate as to why this is not strictly correct?

Answer (score 2):

The contract for `hashcode()` is quite simple:

- If two objects are equal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

A valid hash function for any class of objects could therefore be:

```
@Override
public int hashcode() {
    return 42;
}
```

The contract that equal objects have the same hashcode value is satisfied.

The problem is that classes that use the above hashcode to distribute objects into buckets (eg. `HashSet`) would distribute all objects into the same bucket with severe performance consequences.  An optimal hash function, though not strictly required, would produce distinct values for unequal objects so that they would be distributed to their own buckets.

The contract for `Object.equals()` does not require the use of `hashcode()` when making comparisons.  However, if an immutable object has an expensive equals comparison, it may use the hashcode value to determine whether an expensive comparison is necessary.  The hashcode can be cached the first time it is computed.  Because the object is immutable, the hashcode can not change and so it may be safely cached within the instance. The hashcode can therefore be used as an optimization for equals comparisons: the expensive comparison only need be done on instances with the same hashcode.

Simple algorithms for writing adequate hash functions can be found in Effective Java, 3rd Ed. (J. Bloch).  Modern IDE's can also automatically generate hash functions for you.